# Why does SQL Server use "Binn" directory instead of "Bin"

Tags: sql-server

Just out of pure curiosity, why does SQL Server create a Binn folder

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn
```

and not use a Bin folder as is more common? There must be some reason, surely?

Comment: I just had this same question! thanks for asking!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

[Haidong Ji](http://www.haidongji.com/about-me/), who authored a few books on SQL Server, [claims](http://www.haidongji.com/2008/11/24/resource-database-has-been-moved-to-a-new-location-in-sql-server-2008/) that this is a historic leftover from the 16-to-32-bit migration:

> By the way, do you know why the folder is called Binn? Why two “n”s? There is a bit of history there. Back in the 16-bit days, all binary files were stored under the Bin folder. However, as things moved to 32-bit and Windows NT came to the market, this new folder, Binn, was created to accommodate that. The extra n was taken from NT, which stands for “New Technology”.

Comment: Thanks - but now we are Windows x64, do we need `Binnn`? :P

Comment: @Ryan, or perhaps `Binnnn`. :)

Comment: The interesting quirks that history can take :-)